# Add checkbox to price calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently my price output gets calculated based on the chosen quantity of an input field. I have been trying to add a checkbox to this calculation that, if checked, adds $5 to the total price. That being said, I haven't been very successful. In my understanding, there are two calculations going on:

1. I hit the increase/decrease button and it checks if the checkbox has been selected
2. I select the checkbox and it calculates the total price

This is the code I have so far:

```js
  function IncludePrice()
{
    var IncludePrice=0;
    var include = theForm.elements["include"];
    if(include.checked==true)
    {
        IncludePrice=5;
    }
    return IncludePrice;
}





$(".incr-btn_mobile").on("click", function(e) {
      var $button = $(this);
      var oldValue = $button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
      $button.parent().find('.incr-btn_mobile[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');
      if ($button.data('action') == "increase") {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
      } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below 1
        if (oldValue > 1) {
          var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
          newVal = 1;
          $button.addClass('inactive');
        }
      }
      $button.parent().find('.quantity').val(newVal);

      var cakePrice = newVal;
      var includep = IncludePrice();
      var divobj = document.getElementById($button.attr('data-target'));
      divobj.style.display = 'block';
      divobj.innerHTML = "=&nbsp;&nbsp;$" + (cakePrice) * 7.99 + (includep);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.bg {
 width: 100%;
}


.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    
}



.count-input_mobile {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input_mobile input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #000
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input_mobile input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: none;
    padding: 10.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.sum_output {
    background: none;
    padding: 9.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.accordion_img {
  width:200%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-input_mobile space-bottom">
<a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="decrease" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">–</a>
<input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1" type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
<a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="increase" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">+</a>
</div>      
<label for='include' class="inlinelabel">Include Extra? ($5)</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="include" name='include' data-target="cleanse_drop_1" />
<div id="cleanse_drop_1" class="sum_output">=&nbsp;&nbsp;$7.99</div>
```

> > UPDATE:

I changed made some changes based on the feedback here, but this seems to break the increase/decrease field. Here is the code as is:

```js
$(".incr-btn_mobile").on("click", function(e) {
      var $button = $(this);
      var oldValue = $button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
      $button.parent().find('.incr-btn_mobile[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');
      if ($button.data('action') == "increase") {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
      } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below 1
        if (oldValue > 1) {
          var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
          newVal = 1;
          $button.addClass('inactive');
        }
      }
      $button.parent().find('.quantity').val(newVal);

      var cakePrice = newVal;
      var includep = theForm.elements.include.checked * 5;
      var divobj = document.getElementById($button.attr('data-target'));
      divobj.style.display = 'block';
      divobj.innerHTML = "=&nbsp;&nbsp;$" + (cakePrice) * 7.99 + (includep);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.bg {
 width: 100%;
}


.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    
}



.count-input_mobile {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input_mobile input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #000
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input_mobile input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: none;
    padding: 10.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.sum_output {
    background: none;
    padding: 9.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.accordion_img {
  width:200%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-input_mobile space-bottom">
<a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="decrease" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">–</a>
<input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1" type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
<a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="increase" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">+</a>
</div>      
<label for='include' class="inlinelabel">Include Extra? ($5)</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="include" name='include' data-target="cleanse_drop_1" />
<div id="cleanse_drop_1" class="sum_output">=&nbsp;&nbsp;$7.99</div>
```

Comment: You’re using `IncludePrice` for both the function name and the variable name. Don’t do this. Also, `IncludePrice()` — and thus `includep` — can be replaced by `theForm.elements.include.checked * 5`.

Comment: I added the updated code. Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go my friend. I only change your js code. There is all the change I made:

- Deleted your `IncludePrice` function since you could do it in only    one row. And do never user function name for a variable. It could    possibly break your code.
- All switched for jQuery use instead of half jQuery and native JS.
- Created a function for checkbox `onclick` to change the prince dynamicly.
- I changed the names of your variables to make them more specific.
- Added some comments to make the code clearer.

```js
var _EXTRAVAL = 5;

$(".incr-btn_mobile").on("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set variable for the method
    var button = $(this);
    var labelNb = button.parent().find('.quantity');
    var labelPrice = $("#" + button.attr('data-target'));
    var currentNb = button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
    var newNb = 0;

    // Remove 'inactive' class
    $('.incr-btn_mobile[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');

    // Increase or decrease
    if (button.attr('data-action') == "increase") {
        newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) + 1;
    } else {

        // Don't allow decrementing below 1
        if (currentNb > 1) {
            newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) - 1;
        } else {
            newNb = 1;
            button.addClass('inactive');
        }
    }


    var isExtra = $("#include").prop('checked') ? _EXTRAVAL : 0;
    $(labelNb).val(newNb);
    $(labelPrice).css('display', 'block').html("=  $" + String((((newNb) * 7.99) + (isExtra)).toFixed(2)));
});

$("#include").on('click', function(){
    // Set variable for method
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var labelPrice = $("#" + $(".incr-btn_mobile").attr('data-target'));
    var labelPriceFloat = parseFloat(labelPrice.html().substring(4));
    
    // If checkbox is check, increse price
    if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
        labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat + _EXTRAVAL).toFixed(2)));
    } else {
        labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat - _EXTRAVAL).toFixed(2)));
    }
});
```

```css
.bg {
 width: 100%;
}


.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    
}



.count-input_mobile {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input_mobile input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #000
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.count-input_mobile input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}
.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: none;
    padding: 10.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.sum_output {
    background: none;
    padding: 9.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.accordion_img {
  width:200%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-input_mobile space-bottom">
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="decrease" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">–</a>
  <input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1" type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="increase" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">+</a>
</div>      
<label for='include' class="inlinelabel">Include Extra? ($5)</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="include" name='include' data-target="cleanse_drop_1" />
<div id="cleanse_drop_1" class="sum_output">=  $7.99</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!! Appreciate it and have to put some time into it to learn from it. I got one little issue that the snippet here doesn't seem to have: When I click the checkbox before any increase or decrease, I get a "$NaN" error prompt. Any idea?

Comment: It's probably because of your default value in your html. In this check `onclick` function you can see this line: `var labelPriceFloat = parseFloat(labelPrice.html().substring(4));`. It means it will take the fourth character till the end of the string and extract it. So if this extraction contains character, it will fail because I did a `parseFloat` further.

Comment: In other words, your `div` with the following id: `clease_drop_1` need to be exactly like mine.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve the last step yet, but I should be able to figure it out. Thanks again, you helped me a great deal.

Comment: @FatTwin If you ever need help, feel free to ask me!